# How to specify the rpm packages that a user can install using visudo?

Tags: linux, sudoers, visudo

I need to specify the prefix of the rpms that a specific user can install on a CentOS 7 server. For example, let's say that I have:

- my_package_foo.rpm
- my_package_boo.rpm

I thought that I could add this:

```
my_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/rpm* my_package*
```

But it's not working.

I also tried variations, like:

```
my_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/rpm my_package*
```

Finally I tried like below, but this allows me to install **any** rpm, what I don't want.

```
my_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the problem.

I was trying to install my package using -ivh, but this was not correct in my sudoers file. So I adjusted like this and worked:

```
my_user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/rpm -* my_package*
```

Now I can install using:

```
sudo rpm -ivh my_package_boo.rpm
sudo rpm -e my_package_boo
(...)
```